# App groups and multiple bundle ID's

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, today-extension

Having a ton of issues and frustrations getting a today widget to play nice with signing and provisioning. The main issue being the app has different bundle ID's per scheme, and the extension's AppID and all groups need to match the app's bundle ID.

I've followed a couple of solutions, the latest being the answer from:
[Xcode 8: different entitlements for each scheme causing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466398/xcode-8-different-entitlements-for-each-scheme-causing-errors)

However, it seems xcode keeps manipulating my app groups, adding or removing them from the actual APP ID's, causing provisioning profiles to go bad and no longer work. I manually fix them, and xcode/apple messes them up again.

What are apps doing in this case?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, please double check that you have different info.plists and xxx.entitlement files for every one of your targets.

In my case, 2 of my targets somehow were linked to the same entitlement file so whenever I made a change to one, the other was affected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using user-defined build settings and then using those in other builds settings? Here's an example with Facebook App IDs for different configs:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing. I think the problem is I have 3 bundle ID's for 2 different teams (enterprise/app store). The enterprise team has the same app with 2 bundle ID's and those seem to keep getting confused and removed/deleted. What I'm trying now, is to keep 1 app group per team, even if my enterprise apps end up sharing this group. this may eliminate xcode changing up the groups for that team.

Comment: So for the FB example, do you have these APP_ID's all setup to have different groups for the entitlements? Because that's where my issue seems to be. I can have the app build with a different bundleID with configurations no problem, but once it comes to the groups in entitlements it goes nuts on me

Comment: No, but we do have multiple entitlements files and we change the name of the entitlements file in the build settings using the value of this user-defined variable. Same for info.plist files.