# Xcode auto signing keeps failing

Tags: ios, xcode

Environment:
Xcode 8.3.3

The auto signing problem happens since I removed all the provisioning located at `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles`

Xcode keeps repairing provisioning and never success. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: please set "automatic" & "iOS Developer" in build settings  (target and project) then clear and reset "Automatically manage signing" in general.

Comment: Tried and the signing problem still happening :(

Comment: Are you using your company developer account?

Comment: Yes I am using company developer account.

Comment: seems my problem is related to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466398/xcode-8-different-entitlements-for-each-scheme-causing-errors

Answer (score 0):

The best way is you should create a new **Certificate** with this **Provisioning Profile**, then re-adding it into your Xcode.

Comment: 1. Revoke current certificate in your apple account.
2. Create the new one.
3. Choose new certificate for your bundle id, then build again.
You can check the following link as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858770/create-provisioning-profile-in-ios
Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. The signing works if I import the provisioning manually. However, I have no idea why the auto-signing is not working and it keeps repairing the provisioning I created.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com), create profiles with your bundle id. then downlowd and select it manually at XCode.

Comment: Currently I am using manual import to solve the deployment problem, but I want to fix the auto signing problem.